# jQuery custom content scroller animate

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroller, mcustomscrollbar

I'm trying to make an animation while scrolling with [mCustomScollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)

I'm able to get the current `scrollTop` and make it animate on a specific height with the following code:

```
$("#content").mCustomScrollbar({
    scrollButtons:{
        enable:true
    },
        advanced:{
            updateOnContentResize: true,
            updateOnBrowserResize: true,
    },
    callbacks:{
        onScrollStart:function(){ onScrollStart(); },
        whileScrolling:function(){ WhileScrolling(); } 
    }
});

function WhileScrolling(){
    var top = Math.abs(mcs.top);

    if(top > 180){
        $('#topbar').animate({opacity:'0'});
    }
```

But if I try to make the animation backwards with this code:

```
if(top < 180){
    $('#topbar').animate({opacity:'1'});
}
```

This part fails, and once added, the `animate({opacity:0})` somehow takes a long time before it starts the animation.

preview:

> http://www.alphadesigns.t15.org/

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping any #topbar animations before calling .animate():

```
$('#topbar').stop().animate({opacity:'1'});
$('#topbar').stop().animate({opacity:'0'});
```

more on jQuery .stop() here: 
http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Comment: Thx for the awnser, though it wasnt the stop function.
Using .fadeOut() and .fadeIn() seemed to fix it.